# Sorting a list of electronic components?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In a spreadsheet the bill of materials of electronic components lists the components by their values, for example, 1R0 (for 1 Ohm), 1K0 (for 1 kilo-Ohm),  or 22p (for 22 pico-Farad), 1n0 (for 1 nano-Farad). How can numbers in this format be sorted in numerical order?

**Before, unsorted:**

Resistors

- 1K0
- 1R0

Capacitors

- 1n0
- 22p

**After, sorted:**

Resistors

- 1R0
- 1K0

Capacitors

- 22p
- 1n0

Comment: You'd probably have to create a (possibly hidden) column that has the decimal values for the resistors and then sort by that column. If the column can't be hidden, you could set the font color to be the same as the background color (white, white).

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: What are all the unit notations that you are using? For Ohms, is it only R0 and k0? For Farads, is it only p and n0?

Comment: Ohms: R, k and M. Farads: p n and u.

Comment: @RobKam Just one last thing: Should I assume that for ohms then it is R0, k0, M0 and Farads p, n, u (without the '0'??) Your question presents 'p' and 'n0' as Farad units

Comment: I should have included 0s for the capacitor values as well. The prefix letter acts as the decimal separator, (Ohms and Farads are implicit). 


BTW most of the values likely to be encountered are in the [E96 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers).


The SO question [What is a “100R” resistor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246920/what-is-a-100r-resistor) goes into the background a bit more.

Comment: You could get them into an array and use a [custom sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).  And then return them to the spreadsheet with `setValues()`

Comment: @RobKam Hey Rob, did you manage to sort your elements? Did you have any issue with the provided answers? Please let me know whether you have any. Cheers

Comment: @carlesgg97 I've been offline a few days. I'm having a look at the answers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) in order to sort your values:

```js
var unitMap = {
  'p': 1e-12,
  'n': 1e-9,
  'u': 1e-6,
  'm': 1e-3,
  'R': 1,
  'K': 1e3,
  'M': 1e6,
}

var unitRegex = /[pnumRKM]/;

function parseValue(val) {
  var result = {};
  var unitIdx = val.search(unitRegex);
  var int = parseInt(val.substring(0, unitIdx));
  var dec = parseFloat("0." + val.substring(unitIdx+1));
  var multiplier = unitMap[val[unitIdx]];
  return (int + dec) * multiplier;
}

/**
 * Sorts E96 values.
 *
 * @param {range} input The range to sort.
 * @param {number} input The column to sort by, starting at 1.
 * @param {boolean} input Is ascending
 * @return Sorted range.
 * @customfunction
 */
function CUSTOMSORT(values, sort_column, is_ascending) {
  values.sort(function (a, b) {
    var a_value = parseValue(a[sort_column-1]);
    var b_value = parseValue(b[sort_column-1]);
    return is_ascending ? a_value - b_value : b_value - a_value;
  });

  return values;
}
```

The behaviour is pretty much the same as you would expect from the Sheets' built-in `=SORT()` function, albeit with less features. You can see two examples below:

[image: CUSTOMSORT resistors]

[image: CUSTOMSORT capacitors]

Comment: This works fine, thanks, (only I've left out the parse for millifarads ...).

Answer (score 1):

you can custom sort it like this where you define the sorting order of each scalar:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT({REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\d+)(.*)"), 
               VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+(.*)"), 
 {"R0", 1; 
  "K0", 2; 
  "M0", 3}, 2, 0)}, 3, 1, 1, 1), 999^99, 2))),,999^99)), " ", ))
```

[image: 0]